# how div class can be active when page is refreshed using jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I have created a jquery function to hide or show the content inside div but whenever i reload the page it becomes hide, any resolution for this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myRadioGroup').change(function(){
      var ress = $('#myRadioGroup input[name="cars"]:checked').val();
      if (ress == 3) {
        $('.desc').show();
        $('.descc').hide();
       }
      else{
         $('.desc').hide();
         $('.descc').show();
    }
  });
```

});

and html code is here

```
    <div id="myRadioGroup">
        <input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="cars" value="3">
    </div>
    <div id="Cars2" class="descc">
       2 Cars Selected
    </div>
    <div id="Cars3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
       hello
    </div>
```

Comment: [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) maybe?

Comment: lemme try this.

Comment: Not sure if understand what you really want. I Assume you want it to trigger it once, once your page is loaded. Add `$('#myRadioGroup').change();` at the end of your `$(document).ready(...)` to trigger your event once. So `$(document).ready(function(){ ... $('#myRadioGroup').change(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the simplest solutions for you is `LocalStorage`.

I made some changes to your JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function selectedDefaultValue() {
    var localData = localStorage.getItem("selectedValue");

    if(localData !== null) {
      var radio = $('#myRadioGroup input[value="' + Number(localData) + '"]');

      radio.prop('checked', true);
      onChangeRadio();
    }
  }

  function onChangeRadio() {
    var ress = $('#myRadioGroup input[name="cars"]:checked').val();

    if (ress == 3) {
      $('.desc').show();
      $('.descc').hide();
    } else{
      $('.desc').hide();
      $('.descc').show();
    }
    localStorage.setItem("selectedValue", ress);
  }

  selectedDefaultValue();

  $('#myRadioGroup').change(function(){
    onChangeRadio();
  });
});
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/KKgPyBo

Answer (score 1):

When page is refreshed, it resets. To avoid this, you need to persist the data. There are several ways to handle this:

- Local storage
- Cookies
- URL query params
- API (Store in DB or Cloud services)

If you are dealing with sensitive information, it is in your best interest to go with API method (*on https*). But assuming this isn't sensitive information, you can go with one of the first three methods. From which, I feel localStorage is easier.

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Also, use readable and understandable names. Always assume someone is going through your code and they should not feel annoyed by it.